# How to develop windows assembly on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, assembly, wine

As part of my college courses I need to develop in the assembly language. We study x86 and we develop in the windows environment. I run Linux in my home computer and wouldn't want to go to the CS lab every-time.

Ho do I debug and develop complete windows code in Linux ?

Comment: Why not just run a DOS/Windows VM on your Linux box ?

Comment: Use DOSBOX: http://www.dosbox.com ?

Comment: Will it respond to windows API?

Comment: You'd probably want something like WINE for that I imagine: http://www.winehq.org

Comment: I would suggest asking and talking to your teacher. He might be delighted that you actually use Linux!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I will try, but their is a reason I'm asking on stack. I don't think he will answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the VM option in order to get full compatibility.  VirtualBox is free for that type of use (last time I checked) and if you can afford your books for class, you should certainly be able to afford a single Windows license.  :-)  Then look into MASM32 for your assembler.